# Using ngModel with async pipe in template

Tags: rxjs, angular2-template

I have something like this right now in my template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="state | async as stateObject">
  <select [(ngModel)]="stateObject.name">
    <option>Select</option>
  </select>
<ng-container>
```

My question is how do I get the value of stateObject.name inside my component, because I dont have any subscription in my component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is how do I get the value of stateObject.name inside my component, because I dont have any subscription in my component.

You could do

```
<select [(ngModel)]="stateObject.name" (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)">
    <!-- … -->
</select>
```

And then in your component

```
doSomething (model: State): void {
    console.log(model); // or whatever
}
```

But that doesn't strike me as the best idea. It might be better to not use the `async` pipe here and instead manage the subscription explicitly in your component:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="stateObject">
    <select [(ngModel)]="stateObject">
        <!-- … -->
    </select>
</ng-container>

// ===

@Component({ … })
public YourComponent extends Component implements OnDestroy {

    public stateObject: State;
    private destroy$ = new Subject();

    constructor(private state: StateService) {
        state
            .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
            .subscribe(state => this.stateObject = state);
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.destroy$.next();
        this.destroy$.complete();
    }

}
```

This would also give you better control over what to do if, for example, `state` emits while your form is dirty.

Comment: I didnt want to try the first approach, second one looks better will try